# Payment processing gateway validation policy

Tags: payment-gateway

We work with a 501c3 that has a donation form that's been getting hit with crazy amounts of phishing. The charges weren't being declined, but every 3-5 minutes they were submitting a new $1 donation with a new card number and "Address" as the address.

The bank is telling the client they only validate the information that's on the card - the name, card number, and cvv2. So my question to anyone who's knowledgeable in this area.

Is that common policy or is their bank, FirstTrans, just a bad bank? I feel pretty astonished the address isn't also validated because if the card is stolen they have all the info they need.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

**The Bigger Problem**

If people are phishing and using your site as a utility to test credit card numbers, you should introduce something to prevent automated attempts to do  this. It sounds like you need to introduce a captcha.

**Account Validation**

Generally, "card not present" transactions validate:

- card number
- expiration date
- CVV/CVV2
- cardholder name

Additional AVS checks are configurable; when enabled, they usually mean a lower cost-per-transaction. They are capable of validating:

- zip code
- numeric portion of the address

These are usually enabled on a per-merchant basis.

Comment: Here's where/why I think they need to switch gateways and banks. The Bank shut down the form until we added a captcha like you mentioned, at the same time the client was talking with the gateway and they told the client "Also wanted to let you know that the CAPTCHA is not needed as we use our own API to pass through to Transfirst. The Transfirst rep was supposed to direct to us and they didn’t." It seems like a toxic or uncoordinated relationship that the 501c3 is now stuck between.

Comment: submitted before finishing. So according to the rest of your reply we should probably advise them to switch gateways/bank to one that supports validating the additional measures rather than just the information that would already be present on a stolen card?

Comment: If users need to create an account in order to purchase, you might consider locking the account after a certain amount of failed attempts. Creating new accounts should require a captcha. Alternatively, you can add a captcha to every purchase... although that gets in the way of a purchase experience a little more. Nearly every gateway out there is going to support AVS; Visa and Mastercard may even require it. Has the 501c3 logged into their Merchant portal to attempt to enable it?